# Twitter Firebase login in android

Tags: android, firebase, twitter

I am using Fabric for my Twitter Login. I have installed Fabric in Android Studio. Once I sign in to Fabric, it shows Select your Organization followed by my name and 0 apps.

I am not able to find any app on Fabric. I have registered my app with Firebase. Do I need to register my app with Fabric as well. If yes, how do I do it?

Answer (score 0):

My answer is yes. You also need to register your app with `Fabric`.

Did you follow the instruction to add your app to `Fabric` ?

If yes, please build and run your app on phone or emulator. Then the app should be display in `Fabric` console.

If no, follow the instruction to add your app first. Then build and run your app on phone or emulator.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I think i dont need to add my app to Fabric,as google owns Fabric now.

Comment: Are they any official document that said the project on Firebase will be linked to Fabric?

Comment: Firebase owns Fabric. In January 2017, Google acquired Fabric and Crashlytics from Twitter to join those services to the Firebase team.

Comment: Then I hope Firebase will link the app to Fabric for you with out you doing it by yourself good luck :)